PowerDNSのRecursorがAuthに登録したゾーン情報を返さない
クライアント⇒recursor⇒authの順に名前解決をさせようとしています。
Docker Composeで定義している"dig_test"から"dig"コマンドでテストしています。
テスト前に事前に"webapp"のWeb画面から"auth"に"www.local"を登録しています。
digの問い合わせ先を"auth"にした場合は正常に"www.local"のIPアドレスを回答します。
しかしながら問合せ先を"recursor"に変更した場合にはIPアドレスが空で回答されます。
ちなみに"google.com"などインターネット上の名前解決はしてくれている状況です。
以下に設定の間違いがあればご指摘いただけますでしょうか？
環境：

Docker Desktop for Windows
WindowsのIP: 172.16.1.101/24

docker-compose.yml:
version: '3.0'
services:
  recursor:
    image: powerdns/pdns-recursor-master
    container_name: pdns_recursor
    # restart: always
    ports:
      # - "53:53"
      # - "53:53/udp"
      - "8082:8082"
    volumes:
      - ./recursor/recursor.conf.yml:/etc/powerdns/recursor.conf:ro
    networks:
      powerdns:
        ipv4_address: 172.23.0.2
    # entrypoint: /bin/bash
    # command: /bin/bash
    # tty: true

  auth:
    image: powerdns/pdns-auth-master
    container_name: pdns_auth
    # restart: always
    environment:
      PDNS_AUTH_API_KEY: ABC_DE_F123
    ports:
      - "53:53"
      - "53:53/udp"
      # - "1053:53"
      # - "1053:53/udp"
      - "8081:8081"
    volumes:
      - auth_varlib:/var/lib/powerdns/
      # - ./auth/pdns.conf:/etc/powerdns/pdns.d/pdns.conf:ro
      - ./auth/pdns.conf:/etc/powerdns/pdns.conf:ro
    networks:
      powerdns:
        ipv4_address: 172.23.0.3
    depends_on:
      db:
        condition: service_healthy

  webapp:
    image: powerdnsadmin/pda-legacy:latest
    container_name: powerdns_admin
    # restart: always
    ports:
      - "9191:80"
    logging:
      driver: json-file
      options:
        max-size: 50m
    environment:
      - GUNICORN_TIMEOUT=60
      - GUNICORN_WORKERS=2
      - GUNICORN_LOGLEVEL=DEBUG
    volumes:
      - powerdns_web:/data
    networks:
      powerdns:
        ipv4_address: 172.23.0.4
    
  db:
    image: postgres:16.3
    container_name: powerdns_db
    expose:
      - 5432
    # ports:
    #   - 127.0.0.1:6000:5432
    environment:
      POSTGRES_DB: powerdb
      POSTGRES_ROOT_PASSWORD: redminep
      POSTGRES_USER: powerdns
      POSTGRES_PASSWORD: powerpass
      POSTGRES_INITDB_ARGS: "--encoding=UTF-8"
      TZ: Asia/Tokyo
    volumes:
      - db_data:/var/lib/postgresql/data
      - ./postgresql/:/docker-entrypoint-initdb.d/
    networks:
      powerdns:
        ipv4_address: 172.23.0.5
    healthcheck:
      test: ["CMD", "psql", "-U", "powerdns", "powerdb"]
      interval: 1s
      timeout: 5s
      retries: 3
      start_period: 3s

  dig_test:
    image: ubuntu
    command: bash -c "apt update -y && apt-get install -y dnsutils curl && bash"
    tty: true
    networks:
      powerdns:
        ipv4_address: 172.23.0.6
    dns: 172.23.0.2

volumes:
  powerdns_auth:
    driver: local
  auth_varlib:
  powerdns_web:
    driver: local
  db_data:

networks:
  powerdns:
    driver: bridge
    ipam:
      driver: default
      config:
        - subnet: 172.23.0.0/16
          gateway: 172.23.0.1


recursor.conf:
recursor:
    forward_zones:
    - zone: local
      forwarders:
      - 172.23.0.3

    - zone: 0.23.172.in-addr.arpa
      forwarders:
      - 172.23.0.3

    forward_zones_recurse:
    - zone: .
      forwarders:
      - 8.8.8.8 
      # recurse: true
      # notify_allowed: true

    include_dir: /etc/powerdns/recursor.d

incoming:
  listen:
  - 0.0.0.0
  - '::'

  allow_from:
  - 172.16.1.0/24
  - 172.23.0.0/16

logging:
  loglevel: 7

pdns.conf:
api=yes
webserver=yes
include-dir=/etc/powerdns/pdns.d
# launch=gsqlite3
# gsqlite3-database=/var/lib/powerdns/pdns.sqlite3
local-port=53
security-poll-suffix=
setgid=pdns
setuid=pdns
# DNSゾーン転送を無条件で許可するIPアドレスを書く（PowerDNSキャッシュサーバのIPとRTX830のIP）
allow-axfr-ips=172.23.0.0/16,172.16.1.101
version-string=unknown

# PostgreSQLs
launch=gpgsql
gpgsql-host=powerdns_db
gpgsql-port=5432
gpgsql-dbname=powerdb
gpgsql-user=powerdns
gpgsql-password=powerpass
# gpgsql-extra-connection-parameters=
# gpgsql-prepared-statements=yes
gpgsql-dnssec=no


自己解決しました。
原因はコンテナ間で時刻がバラバラだったことが原因なようです。
YMLファイルの各サービスに以下の内容を追記して解決しました。
    cap_add:
      - SYS_TIME

自己解決するためにはRecursorでDNSクエリのログが必要でしたが質問文の設定では不十分でした。
"logging"セクションを以下の内容に変更することでDNSクエリのログが出力されるようになりました。
logging:
  loglevel: 7

  common_errors: true
  quiet: false
  trace: yes

